# Postgresql dump with data restriction

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-administration

I'm working on developing a fast way to make a clone of a database to test an application. My database has some specif tables that are quite big (+50GB), but the big majority of the tables only have a few MBs. On my current server, the dump + restore takes some hours. These bigs tables have date fields.

With the context in mind, my question is: Is possible to use some type of restrictions on table rows to select the data that is being dumped? e.g. On table X only dump the rows that date is Y.

If this is a possible show can I do it? if it's not possible what would be a good alternative?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `COPY SELECT whatever FROM yourtable WHERE ... TO '/some/file'` to limit what you export.

[`COPY` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [row level security](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html) and create a policy that lets the dumping database user see only those rows that you want to dump (make sure that that user is neither a superuser nor owns the tables, because these users are exempt from row level security).

Then dump the database with that user, using the `--enable-row-security` option of `pg_dump`.